# How to properly delimit data in php plain file

Tags: php, file, escaping, explode, plaintext

I want to store millions of data lines (containing url, title, description)...
Something like this:

```
url:example.com|title:some title|description: some description
url:example2.com|title:some other title|description: some other description
```

I don't understand the logic or the proper way to select a delimiter and to escape the actual data containing that delimiter.

Is it a good approach to use double character `||` and then replace any `|` in actual data to `\|` ? 
That way I can look for `||title:` with zero chances of it existing in actual title text, because there it would be `\|\|title:`

Is there a better solution for that ?

**Edit:** The different lines can also contain different variables like url meta tags and there is no fixed predefined list of these variables, so I think this prevents me from storing them in a csv format.

I know I could encode/decode these as json but that would complicate the application too much.

Comment: Take for example the "rules" for CSV: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules

Comment: FYI: https://php.net/fputcsv. Yes, you could do it "by hand" but why. Don't reinvent the wheel. This php function will do everything for you w/o you having to worry about side effects.

Comment: If you want this to performa like anything other than lukewarm garbage you should really put this in a database of some kind.

Comment: I think the csv approach would not work because my variables are not always there , different lines might have different variables present, maybe even in different order, I will add that to my question.

Comment: Empty values can be represented in CSV. It's far better and I recommend that you keep consistency in your data structure (i.e. always have the same number of columns allowing for empties). Or go for a noSQL database collection.

Comment: Yes, empty values exist in csv format, but some of my urls (lines) can have new fields ... the variable names are dynamic too and I just store what I find, but I don't have a fixed list of variable names. Storing very different URL meta tag names for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think for me I would import that data into a database and merge/join the columns using some select statement, then export out to csv.